# Horror movie: Last scene of the movie: woman coming out of another woman's vagina, and then taking the latter's place

Tags: story-identification, movie, horror

I saw this movie 2-3 yrs back but it's not older than 2000 for sure. The movie scene and quality was really good, the grotesqueness of that scene was comparable to those scenes of the Serbian film. I only remember the video of it playing in my mind, it may or may not be English.

The only pieces of it that I remember were the kind of last(?) scenes of it in which a fully grown girl (or woman) was coming out of the vagina of this woman. As if she was trapped inside of her, and feeding and eating her bones (bone-cracking scenes were there too, I recall).

The body of this outer woman was being deformed as if was a pile of skin falling to the ground. And then the new girl went on to live the routine of the older woman, as if she knew what everything was; and even went on to later have sex with her husband. She hid the pile of skin and lived as if nothing had happened.

Comment: Hmmm...reminiscent of *Society*

Comment: To whoever voted to close as too broad, why? How many movies fitting that scenario can you quote? oO

Comment: I have read a short story about a woman giving birth to herself over and over again... 24 hour life span. I *think* it was in Zelazny's *Unicorn Variations*, but may have by another author in a different anthology (something in *Mirrorshades*?).

Comment: https://m.imdb.com/list/ls002338192/ might be useful

Comment: Someone asnwered it thanku...

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's been awhile since I watched it but this sounds vaguely like the final "Letter" of ABC's of Death 2.

Z is for Zygote

> A pregnant woman is left by herself by her husband who leaves her "midwife root" to prevent the baby from being born. 13 years later, the woman is still pregnant, but the child has grown inside of her and can speak. The woman does not want her child to leave, even though it is slowing her down and is shocked when the root runs out. The child then kills its mother and disembowels her, wearing her skin. Ti, the husband, returns and not knowing that his wife is actually his child offers to start fresh.

[ABCs of Death 2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ABCs_of_Death_2)

Comment: I don't know how long the link will last, but you can view the segment at https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=N0PpSP8LrG0

Comment: Yess thanku... omg ... u found it ...